# Why Converting Observable to WritableSignal in Angular 16 throw error of missing properties

Tags: angular, angular16, angular-signals

I have the following simple code on my component:

```
import {Component, effect, signal, WritableSignal} from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from "../app.service";
import {toSignal} from "@angular/core/rxjs-interop";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  translations: WritableSignal<{data: {}}> = signal({data: []});

  constructor( private appService: AppService) {
    this.translations = toSignal(this.appService.getTranslations());
    effect(() => {
      console.log('translation API:', this.translations());
    });
  }

  changeValue(): void {
    this.translations.set({data: {hello: 'hallo'}})

  }
}
```

FYI: `this.appService.getTranslations()` returns an observable

I'm trying out the new features released with Angular v16, and how to convert Observables to Signals.

What I wanted to do on the above code is, I change the value of the WritableSignal Object and log its value on change.

I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2739: Type 'Signal ' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableSignal{ data: {}; }>': set, update, mutate, asReadonly
```

Help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observables are "read-only", and thus unsuitable for a `WritableSignal`. You can subscribe to them, but not call a method like `next` to push new data.
Subjects could potentially be converted to a `WritableSignal`, but there is no utility method as far as I know.

What the error you get means is that the object `Signal`, which is returned by `toSignal`, is missing properties/methods from `WritableSignal`, all the "write" ones; `Signal` is the "read-only" version of `WritableSignal`.

For this case, you should subscribe to your observable, and set the signal in the callback.
If `AppService` uses `HttpClient` behind the scenes, no need to unsubscribe since it is done automatically on the first success callback.

```js
constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  this.appService.getTranslations().subscribe(data => {
    this.translations.set(data)
  });
  effect(() => {
    console.log('translation API:', this.translations());
  });
}
```

If it's not using `HttpClient`, and you only want to retrieve the data one time on construction, use the `first()` RxJS operator.

```js
constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  this.appService.getTranslations().pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
    this.translations.set(data)
  });
  effect(() => {
    console.log('translation API:', this.translations());
  });
}
```

If it's not using `HttpClient`, and you need to get regular updates, you have to unsubscribe on destroy.
Since you are testing the Angular 16 developer preview, you can use the new `DestroyRef` for this rather than the `OnDestroy.ngOnDestroy` hook.

```js
constructor(
  private appService: AppService,
  destroyRef: DestroyRef
) {
  const sub = this.appService.getTranslations().subscribe(data => {
    this.translations.set(data)
  });
  destroyRef.onDestroy(() => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  });
  effect(() => {
    console.log('translation API:', this.translations());
  });
}
```

And finally, if you still want to use `toSignal`, your `translations` field has to be of type `Signal`. But then, your `changeValue` method will no longer work as `Signal` does not have a method `set`.